# Is this behaviour expected for GetValueOrDefault in Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper, nullable

We had a problem yesterday regarding a date set to the default DateTime, and tracked the problem down to AutoMapper.
In one of our profiles, we have `x.DueDate.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.Today)`, where `DueDate` is `DateTime?`. The expectation is that the expression results in `DateTime.Today` if `x.DueDate == null`.
This piece of code was working as expected until we updated AutoMapper to the last version, we went from 10.0.0 to 11.0.1.
Here's a minimal reproduction of this:

```
using AutoMapper;

var a = new ClassA { DueDate = null };
var config = new MapperConfiguration(c => c.AddProfile<Prof>());
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
var b = mapper.Map<ClassA, ClassB>(a);
Console.WriteLine(b);

public class ClassA
{
    public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() => $"{{ {nameof(DueDate)}: {DueDate} }}";
}

public class ClassB
{
    public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() => $"{{ {nameof(ExpirationDate)}: {ExpirationDate} }}";
}

public class Prof : Profile
{
    public Prof()
    {
        CreateMap<ClassA, ClassB>()
            .ForMember(b => b.ExpirationDate, cf => cf.MapFrom(a => a.DueDate.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.Today)));
    }
}
```

The project configuration is this

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="11.0.2-alpha.0.12" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The output in this case is `{ ExpirationDate: 1/1/0001 00:00:00 }`.
This happens with both version 11.0.1 and 11.0.2-alpha.0.12. Going back to version 10.0.0 gives the expected output `{ ExpirationDate: 18/8/2022 00:00:00 }`.

Comment: Yes, that method won't be called for `null`. Use a `Func` based resolver instead or any other alternative that works for you.

Comment: `a.DueDate ?? DateTime.Today` works and looks beter.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Yes that was the fix we used, just wanted to know if there's something we were missing in order to avoid other problems.